# Slideable Action with Future Method

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to use [Flutter_slideable](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable) with future method. My code's sample is below:

```
SlidableAction(
onPressed: (BuildContext context) {
usemethod(context,item.number);
 },
 backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
foregroundColor: Colors.white,
icon: Icons.play_arrow,
label: 'use',)
```

in this case usemethod is a future get method. How can I arrange this code in proper way? I don't get any specific error and also I know that the future method is correct.

Comment: Can you provide more info? What is your goal?

Comment: Can you describe more, like what is `usemethod` and what are you trying to archive? You can check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sure. Actually trying to call an api with parameter of property of the element in the listview. So, when slide the element in the listview I get an slideable button, when the clicked that button I want to get an response according to item's property. I have just noticed I wrote code wrongly you can think like usemethod(context, item.number).

Comment: Do you think that ok the way that I use to call future method?

Answer (score 0):

If you call a future method, you need to do put await in front of the method and get response then check if the future method is returned what you want. Here;

```
SlidableAction(
onPressed: (BuildContext context) async {
     var response = await usemethod(context,item.number);
     //check here if the response as you want with conditions.
 },
 backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFE4A49),
foregroundColor: Colors.white,
icon: Icons.play_arrow,
label: 'use',)
```